# enumitem: description with unbold item - math mode (hepthesis)

Tags: enumitem, description, boldmath, hepthesis

I would like to have a normal font symbol (in math mode) as description item in the hepthesis document class.
**Example:**

```
\documentclass{hepthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{mainmatter}
        $T$ as in test. (This is what I want.)
        \begin{description}
                \item[$T$] as in test. (This is the default.)
                \item[\textmd{$T$}] as in test. (No.)
                \item[\mdseries $T$] as in test. (No.)
                \item[$\unboldmath T$] as in test. (No.)
        \end{description}
        \begin{description}[format=\mdseries]
                \item[$T$] as in test.
        \end{description}
\end{mainmatter}
\end{document}
```

[image: My output:]

But how?

Comment: `\begin{description}[before={\renewcommand\makelabel[1]{\normalfont ##1}}]`

Comment: @HarishKumar Yes, thank you! Would you mind to post this an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine the `\makelabel` using `before` key:

```
\documentclass{hepthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{mainmatter}
        $T$ as in test. (This is what I want.)
        \begin{description}[before={\renewcommand\makelabel[1]{\normalfont ##1}}]
                \item[$T$] as in test.
        \end{description}
\end{mainmatter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May be here it's cleaner with `\SetEnumitemKey` (to have some sort of shortcut) or even apply this gobally with `\setlist`.

Comment: @Manuel It depends on the requirements of OP.

Answer (score 1):

This is a deliberate choice by the class:

```
%% Misc tweaks
\AtEndOfClass{%
  %% Make maths in titles go automatically bold
  \g@addto@macro\bfseries{\boldmath}
  %% Declare a bold version of the typewriter font
  \DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtt}{bx}{n}{<5><6><7><8><9><10><10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>cmttb10}{}
}
```

I find this completely wrong: physicists should know very well that there is a big difference between a symbol and its boldface version: the letter *T* would mean a scalar, whereas ***T*** would be a vector.

You would have the same problem with math in a section title, where all of your scalars would become vectors. My proposed fix is thus to remove the “`\boldmath` in titles” tweak:

```
\edef\bfseries{\noexpand\protect\expandafter\noexpand\csname bfseries \endcsname}
```

or, with `etoolbox`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\bfseries}{\boldmath}{}{}{}
```

Full example

```
\documentclass{hepthesis}

\edef\bfseries{\noexpand\protect\expandafter\noexpand\csname bfseries \endcsname}

\begin{document}

$T$ as in test. (This is what I want.)
\begin{description}
\item[$T$] as in test. (This is the default.)
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Note 1

Your attempt with `\unboldmath` placed it in the wrong position: such a command should go outside math: `\item[\unboldmath$T$]`.

#### Note 2

The patch done by the class, besides being mathematically wrong, is wrong also from the LaTeX point of view: the command to patch is not `\bfseries`, but its internal version that has a trailing space in its name:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\bfseries}{\boldmath}
```

Comment: why are the two lines in your example not aligned anymore? (Thank you for the write-up and for note one.)

Comment: @DisplayName One is a normal paragraph, the second line is a `description`

Answer (score 0):

Still simpler:

```
\documentclass{hepthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{mainmatter}
        $T$ as in test. (This is what I want.)
        \begin{description}[font=\mdseries]
                \item[hehe! $T$] as in test.
        \end{description}
\end{mainmatter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try your answer? I still see the "T" with a different format.

Comment: posted a snapshot of the .pdf. The only point is I don't have `hepthesis` installed, and I replaced it with book. I don't think this makes a difference.

Comment: @Bernard, strange. The enumitem package manual claims format is a synonymous of font, but format did not work for me. (And neither does font.) (I am too slow...)

Comment: If it didn't make a difference I wouldn't have written my comment. This is what you get with `hepthesis` as in your code: http://imgur.com/2CoRPrP

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I've identified the culprit in hepthesis.cls (a tweak line 332), and I propose a workaround with `etools`.

Comment: I withdrew the workaround, which has side effects inside the description environment.